# there is a problem that process is not defined and why? or how it can be defined ? to make program work?

Tags: python

There is no error but there is a problem that process is not defined, why?
And how can it be defined to make the program work?

I mean how can I use class process outside the class?

```py
class Process:
    def convert1(self,typedkm):
        meter = typedkm*1000
        return meter
    def convert2(self,typedkm):
        kilometer = typedm/1000
        return kilometer

def menu():
    ask = None
    while ask != 'q':
        print('KM TO M Convertor Menu')
        print('a) KM To M Convertor')
        print('b) M To KM Convertor')
        print('c) Both')
        print('q) Quit')
        print("\n")

        ask = input("Action: ")

        if ask == 'a':
            try:
                typedkm = float(input("Please Enter Kilometers: "))
                self.Process.convert1(typedkm)
            except:
                print("\n")
                print("Please Enter Right Digits")  
                print("\n")

        elif ask == 'b':
            try:
                typedm = float(input("Please Enter Meters: "))
                self.Process.convert2(typedm)
            except:
                print("\n")
                print("Please Enter Right Digits")  
                print("\n")

menu()
```

Comment: What do you think "self" is there?

Comment: nope, but .....

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I don't know why you say there's no error, cause you should get a NameError since `self` isn't defined in `menu`. Looks like you just need to remove `self.`. Otherwise, you need to make a [mre]. You can [edit] the question.